# Moving objects in Xcode without adding to underlying object

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, ide, xcode5

I'm trying to move object in Xcode's storyboard editor, but I can't find the key combination to use so that the object does not het appended to underlaying view.

My case:

```
TOP
Button
SubView - UIView
    Image
    Label
BOTTOM
```

I'm trying to move the button, but Xcode automatically adds it to SubView, so result is like:

```
TOP    
SubView - UIView
    Image
    Label
    Button
BOTTOM
```

I'm animating the SubView on Button tap, so Button can't be in the SubView.

Is that possible without manually selecting the object in object tree and editing position manually?

Answer (score 0):

While you're dragging your button down to the bottom of the object list, once it's in the vertical location you want, drag it left. Like, further left than you think you should have to, until the correct parent view is highlighted.

Comment: Yea, I found that out, but my question is not about object list but about the storyboard editor(where you can see the components like on screen), sorry for not being clear on that.